# Creating equally spaced points within shapefile with multiple polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, point-in-polygon

In QGIS 2.18.  I have a vector shapefile with multiple polygons, all of these are squared and have their own attributes. Inside these polygons I will have more (small) polygons that will represent areas where it cannot be constructed.

I need to create as many points as possible within each square but excluding the inner polygons (mountains). The points should be equally spaced (i.e. 250 m) from each other and cannot be placed in the edge of the bigger polygon, necessarily have to be inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can create those points using regular points tools in qgis. Unfortunately, it will create points inside the small polygons too. but you can select those points using select by location and delete them.

Comment: I have tried this but it's not what I need. I think I will have to do it with Python

Comment: @Daniel it is not clear from your question that you needed it in Python. Please, edit your question and also show what you have tried so far

Comment: I do not need it in Python, but given that I cannot solve it in QGIS and I cannot find answers here I will give it a try.